# Merge two paragraphs together and deleting an element in middle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div contentEditable with paragraphs and appended after each p is a span telling me the length of the paragraph the user can edit the line & thus update the number shown in the span, (done with something on these lines .each(fu..(){ p append '<span>'+ this.length ..)

Let's say something like this:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
<p>abc<span contenteditable="false" style="position:absolute;right:-2em;backg...">3</span></p>
<p>abce<span ...>4</span></p>
<p>abcfoo<span ...>6</span></p>
<p>abcbar<span ...>6</span></p>
</div>
```

Have made all the spans uneditable  in order to protect the spans and the text, on hitting return a new <p> is created on the next line - all sparky! However I have no way of deleting a new paragraph as the back button on the first letter of a p acts as the browser back button! because its hitting the non editable span.

So I would like to add a button (perhaps on the span) which when clicked will 1. remove the span (not too difficult), 2. merge the 2 paragraphs together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope that's the effect you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/AwKkB/

**JS**

```
$('span').click(function () {
    var parent = $(this).parent(), container = parent.parent();
    $(this).remove();    
    if (container.children().length > 1) {
        if (parent[0] === container.children()[0]) {
            $(container.children()[1]).prepend(parent.text());
        } else {
            parent.prev().append(parent.text());
        }
    }
    parent.remove();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div contenteditable="true" style="width: 180px">
<p>abc<span contenteditable="false" style="position:absolute;right:0em;background: red;">3</span></p>
<p>defg<span contenteditable="false" style="position:absolute;right:0em;background: red;">4</span></p>
<p>hijklm<span contenteditable="false" style="position:absolute;right:0em;background: red;">6</span></p>
<p>nopqrs<span contenteditable="false" style="position:absolute;right:0em;background: red;">6</span></p>
</div>
```

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
$(document).on('click', 'span', function() {
    $(this)
        .prev().append($(this).next().text()).end()
        .next().remove().end()
        .remove()
    ;
});
```

[See Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/anstosa/XZqEu/)

Comment: Really? It's merging them for me in Chrome. The two paragraphs to be merged get wrapped in the same pair of `<p>` tags. They are not in the same `textNode`s but that shouldn't affect rendering at all.

Comment: seems like that is the problem that they aren't on the same text node

Comment: Ah okay, [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anstosa/XZqEu/1/). That one merges the `textNode`s as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether the paragraphs contain only plain text, but a generalised way would be using `.append`, so that all elements are left intact: http://jsfiddle.net/tb7xk/.

```
$("<input>")
.attr({ type: "button", value: "Remove" })
.click(function() {
    var $span = $(this).parent();
    var c = $span.next().contents().get(); // contents
    $.fn.append.apply($span.prev(), c); // pass all contents to .append
    $span.next().andSelf().remove(); // remove next paragraph that's left over
})
.appendTo("span");
```

Comment: @webestdesigns: It is merging them for me in Chrome.

Comment: it works perfectly! thanks alot & your code is a good teacher!!